# spring boot maven plugin not includes all the files within source folder

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a Spring boot project with below structure. But it is not including ui and static folder. below is the snippet of pom.xml plugin. How to include these folders and it's content.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Below is the project strucutre

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing packaging from jar to war solved the problem.

```
<!-- <packaging>jar</packaging> -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
```